# Spacemacs and org-mode configuration problem

Tags: org-mode, org-export, spacemacs

I recently started using Spacemacs. With the default configuration, everithing works fine, but I would like to change a few configurations to org-mode, so i changed the `dotspacemacs/user-config` function to this:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (with-eval-after-load 'org
    (unless (boundp 'org-latex-classes)
      (setq org-latex-classes nil))
    (add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
                 '("koma-article"
                   "\\documentclass{scrartcl}"
                   ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
                   ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
                   ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
                   ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
                   ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
    (org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages
                                 '((dot . t)
                                   (maxima . t)
                                   (python . t)))
    (setq org-babel-python-command "python3")
    ;; Settings to export code with `minted' instead of `verbatim'.
    (setq org-export-latex-listings t)
    (setq org-latex-listings 'minted
          org-latex-packages-alist '(("" "minted"))
          org-latex-pdf-process
          '("pdflatex -shell-escape -intera")))
  )
```

After that, every time I try to export an org file to LaTeX I receive the following error:

```
user-error: Unknown LaTeX class ‘article’
```

What is happening? What did I do wrong? How do I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You blew the default value of `org-latex-classes` away in line 4. Try this instead. I'm waiting for `ox-latex` to load before touching `org-latex-classes`.

```el
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (with-eval-after-load 'org
    (org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages
                                 '((dot . t)
                                   (maxima . t)
                                   (python . t)))
    (setq org-babel-python-command "python3"))
  (with-eval-after-load 'ox-latex
    (add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
                 '("koma-article"
                   "\\documentclass{scrartcl}"
                   ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
                   ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
                   ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
                   ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
                   ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
    ;; Settings to export code with `minted' instead of `verbatim'.
    (setq org-export-latex-listings t)
    (setq org-latex-listings 'minted
          org-latex-packages-alist '(("" "minted"))
          org-latex-pdf-process
          '("pdflatex -shell-escape -intera"))))
```